# How to make drop down post title

Tags: php, ajax, dropdown, select

I am developing a website using WP CMS where I want to implement post title as drop-down list as well as when users select a drop-down title the content show below within reload. I am here. What will I do if I want to retrieve content by id?

```
function select_options(){ ?>

     <form action="" method="POST">
     <select name="count" id="selectId" >
     <?php  

     $posts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type' => 'post')); 
     while($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
        <option id="selection" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></option>
     <?php endwhile;
     die()
     ?>
     </select>
    </form>
    <?php 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_select_option', 'select_options');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_select_option', 'select_options');
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                //var count = $('#selection').val();
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                data:{
                    action: 'select_option'
                    //count: count;
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data){
                    jQuery('.content').html(data)
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert(fail)
                }
            })

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the wp_ajax_ action in an init action.

In fact, wp_ajax_ action need to be accessable from anywhere. Use of the init action hook could make it work like it does.

Hope it works